# Angular rapidly refreshes item loaded from local storage

Tags: angular, google-chrome, local-storage

In my angular application, i built a cache of the users most recent activities (e.g. all the search results that were clicked) and store it in the browser's local storage in order to provide the ability to go back to visited pages.

I then display a list of cards that each represent an entry from the array from the local storage. Each of the cards is clickable and returns to the visited details page.

The problem is, that angular seems to keep refreshing the entries and at the moment of refresh, the item is not clickable. That means I always have to click the list entry several times before the event actually goes through.

If I just store the entries in a local array instead of the browser's local storage, everything works fine.

Here's the relevant code:

cache.component.html:

```
<div class="scrollbar-horinzontal">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cacheEntry of cacheService.getFromBrowserCache()">
      <div>List item content goes here... </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

cache-service.ts (shared service)

```
getFromBrowserCache(): CacheItem[] {
    let cacheItems: CacheItem[]= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.getLocalStorageKey()));
    if (cacheItems == null) {
      cacheItems = [];
    }
    return cacheItems;
}
```

Comment: This is because you are calling a function from your html. You can avoid this by doing the `getFromBrowserCache()` call in your  typescript perhaps `ngOnInit` and then saving the results to a variable to use in your `*ngFor`.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it! Thank you so much! If you make this an answer I will flag it!

Comment: Glad it helped i have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling a function from your html. You can avoid this by doing the getFromBrowserCache() call in your typescript perhaps ngOnInit and then saving the results to a variable to use in your *ngFor.

**Cache Component ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cacheService.getFromBrowserCache().subscribe(data => {
        this.cache = data;
    })
}
```

**Cache Component html**

```
<div class="scrollbar-horinzontal">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cacheEntry of cache">
      <div>List item content goes here... </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked for me. It came with some manual updating of the local variable in typescript when the cache updated, but now it works like a charm!